# Getting a re-ocurring Non Authorised error in running requests

Tags: json, jmeter

I use jmeter for running microservices testing.
I am on version 4 and it has been on the whole working normally.
Just lately though, I am often seeing a 
{
:   "error": "Not Authorised"
}
response in running requests.
This is after a successful login to the application I am testing.

What is also unusual is that the request is coming back with a Response code of: 200, so The endpoint is obviously being hit OK as per the filepath which the developers have built is the correct one I am pointing to.

I have tried changing the Cookie policy setting in case this is storing old sessions data, but that has not resolved the problem.

Can someone suggest anything I can try to resolve this?

Regards
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding:-

1. Use Keep-Alive option in the HTTP Sampler.
2. Check if there is any change in the authentication mechanism on the server.
3. Check if there is any limit introduced for the max number of connection.
4. Check if there is multiple request in a single request but the main request is passing while inner request is failing. In that case, you can get 200 Ok but in the response message you can see some errors.
5. Check if there is a refresh token required after some time. By that I means, if there is a timeout set for a particular token value that is required by the request for authentication.
6. Check if the same is happening while running manually using any sniffing tool like fiddler.
7. Check if there is network interruption intermittently.

Above is what I can think of as of now. This is just on high level and you can drop what you can think is not the case. I hope you will get more inputs from experts if the above is not able to identify any.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help sunny_teo, I will try going through each of those and let you know it they resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the requests are failing due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter). In the majority of cases you cannot just record the test and replay it successfully, modern applications widely use dynamic parameters for starting and maintaining sessions, tracking client-side state, etc.

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan
2. Make sure to inspect request details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Pay special attention to request parts which change. The dynamic part can be also in the request header, URL, parameters, etc.